# Have no access to my VM instances, no sufficient permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I lost my access to my VM instances. I am a student at the University of Melbourne, thus I tried to use GCP with my google account provided by the university (***@student.unimelb.edu.au).

I created my VM instances and I am still able to SSH to my VM, however, I lost my access to it via GCP Dashboard. And here goes the error code:

> You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:
>
> Project
>
> resourcemanager.projects.get

And when I checked API with troubleshooter, it says

> You do not have the required permissions to make this request. Please
>   contact your organization administrator.

I don't think I have done anything concerning administrative problems, why did I lose control of my instances?

Answer (score 1):

Your permissions have been limited. like the message say, try to contact your University administrator to know more. If your project is billed to the University, University is organisation admin and can do anything on its own domain.

Is your VM respected the rules of your university? What was its size? did you mining on it? did you install unauthorized software? At administration level, Google provide a lot of metrics and alert about abnormal resource usage. Maybe you broke a rule.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you had permission before creating the instance, to view the instance ?
With the error you are talking about maybe you didn't have access from the start itself. You would have been given access to create, but not to list VMs. I found the access-control of GCP very complex, you can have access to many things through CLI, but to get the same through console, you need to be granted more accesses.

Ask your admin to provide your account, one of the `viewer` or `editor` or maybe `browser` roles from here: 
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj

Or may be as guillaume suggested you might have broken a rule ;)